# Are there better monadic abstraction alternative for representing long running, async task?

Tags: scala, asynchronous, monads

A `Future` is good at representing a single asynchronous task that will / should be completed within some fixed amount of time.

However, there exist another kind of asynchronous task, one where it's not possible / very hard to know exactly when it will finish. For example, the time taken for a particular string processing task might depend on various factors such as the input size.

For these kind of task, detecting failure might be better by checking if the task is able to make progress within a reasonable amount of time instead of by setting a hard timeout value such as in `Future`.

Are there any libraries providing suitable monadic abstraction of such kind of task in Scala?

Comment: Rather than seeking a specifically monadic abstraction for this, I would be thinking about how I might set up an actor system to break the work into parts and field the parts out to workers, tracking progress through a monitoring actor of some kind.

Comment: `Future` is not the right abstraction for your problem. Perhaps, setup and launch a separate Actor. And: `if the task is able to make progress within a reasonable amount of time` sounds more like a heartbeat mechanism. you could set it up using a messaging system ( like Akka ). @Shadowlands is right, that you should decompose your problem into sub-problems.

Comment: Yes, akka actor is what I currently use but a monadic construct is much simpler to compose and reason about.

Comment: "is making progress" and the functional ideas of immutability and referential transparency seem rather in conflict. Are monads the right model here?

Comment: @TheArchetypalPaul If viewed from that perspective, even a `Future` encodes a state, i.e., running and finished (success/failed). However, the state are not exposed to us and operations are provided in a monadic way. With that being said, I think it is not impossible to model a long-running task as a monadic construct by carefully hiding the progress state by providing monadic operators, thus exposing only the "functional" side of the construct.

Comment: OK, but I'm not sure how you match up "making progress" (and the implication that you want to see that it is) with "carefully hiding the progress state". Cold you add some more about how you might expect this to work? In what way does whether or not the operation is making progress impact your model?

Answer (score 2):

You could use a stream of values like this:

```
sealed trait Update[T]
case class Progress[T](value: Double) extends Update[T]
case class Finished[T](result: T) extends Update[T]
```

let your task emit Progress values when it is convenient (e.g. every time a chunk of the computation has finished), and emit one Finished value once the complete computation is finished. The consumer could check for progress values to ensure that the task is still making progress. If a consumer is not interested in progress updates, you can just filter them out. I think this is more composable than an actor-based approach.

Depending on how much performance or purity you need, you might want to look at [akka streams](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/scala.html) or [scalaz streams](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz-stream). Akka streams has a pure DSL for building flow graphs, but allows mutability in processing stages. Scalaz streams is more functional, but has lower performance last I heard.

Answer (score 0):

You can break your work into chunks. Each chunk is a `Future` with a timeout - your notion of reasonable progress. Chain those Futures together to get a complete task.

Example 1 - both chunks can run in parallel and don't depend on each other (embarassingly parallel task):

```
val chunk1 = Future { ... } // chunk 1 starts execution here
val chunk2 = Future { ... } // chunk 2 starts execution here
val result = for {
  c1 <- chunk1
  c2 <- chunk2
} yield combine(c1, c2)
```

Example 2 - second chunk depends on the first:

```
val chunk1 = Future { ... } // chunk 1 starts execution here
val result = for {
  c1 <- chunk1
  c2 <- Future { c1 => ... } // chunk 2 starts execution here
} yield combine(c1, c2)
```

There are obviously other constructs to help you when you have many Futures like `sequence`.

Answer (score 0):

The article "The worst thing in our Scala code: Futures" by [Ken Scambler](https://github.com/kenbot) points the need for a separation of concerns:

> - `scala.concurrent.Future` is built to work naturally with `scala.util.Try`, so our code often ends up clumsily using `Try` everywhere to represent failure, using raw exceptions as failure values even where no exceptions get thrown.
> - To do anything with a `scala.concurrent.Future`, you need to lug around an implicit `ExecutionContext`. This obnoxious dependency needs to be threaded through everywhere they are used.

So if your code does not depend directly on `Future`, but on simple Monad properties, you can abstract it with a `Monad` type:

```
trait Monad[F[_]] {
  def flatMap[A,B](fa: F[A], f: A => F[B]): F[B]
  def pure[A](a: A): F[A]
}

// read the type parameter as “for all F, constrained by Monad”.
final def load[F[_]: Monad](pageUrl: URL): F[Page]
```